# How to use trait to add new method to class in Scala?

Tags: scala, traits

I have 3rd party class A:

```
class A {
  def methodA = ...
}
```

I want to use use trait to add a new method *methodT* to an instance of `A`

```
trait Atrait[...] {
  def methodT = {
    // how to get a reference of instance of type A?
  }
}
```

This *methodT* is specific to some situation, so I should use constraint in the trait. But I could not figure it out. Also, how can I invoke instance of `A`'s method in a trait?

**UPDATE**

*Trait* doesn't work this way. See answer for alternative solution.

Comment: @KimStebel...yep...*trait* doesn't work that way :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the standard pattern for adding a method to a 3rd party class:

```
class A

implicit class ExtendedA(val a: A) extends AnyVal {
  def methodT: Unit = { println("called A.methodT") }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
val a = new A
a.methodT
```